# GAS Drive: How to product list of all files in all drives of my domain?

Tags: google-apps-script

We have a need to export a list of *all of our files* which includes the filename, owner, and sharing permissions (Anyone, Domain, Specific people). 
I have tried both "GAM" and "Google Apps script" for that matter, and they both failed to produce a detailed and human-readable format of the sharing permissions. Do you know any other tool or the right syntax\script to produce that list?

Actually, I have a "GAS" script that produces just what I need, but it's limited to the user who runs the script, which means if I run it, for example, it will produce a list of only I own and not other "drives". Is there any way to bypass it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For you to share the files to other users inside your Drive, you can sign-in to [GSuite or Drive Enterprise](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2490026?hl=en) for Drive management. You can also check the [Authorization](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization) documentation for more details. Apps Script determines the authorization scopes (like access your Google Sheets files or Gmail) automatically, based on a scan of the code. Code that is commented out can still generate an authorization request. If a script needs authorization, you'll see one of the authorization dialogs shown here when it is run.